# validate the rating directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that creates a rating control  and on click rate it.I don't want to submit the form without user rating that is required validation I don't know how to do that using angularjs.

```
<div jb-rating ng-model="question.answer"  
    rating-value="question.answer" max="5" 
    on-rating-selected="question.answer" 
    read-only="false">
</div>
```

This way i have used the directive but unable to add required validation.

The demo code is on this link:http://plnkr.co/edit/XZAoCYz1eyC9ulC735zS?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very nice case for the custom control, documented at the beginning of the `NgModelController` documentation ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)). You have to make several changes, but it works great: http://plnkr.co/edit/4hq1L5scjnQWvE6WaFyx

Let's review the changes:

1. Use the `ng-model`. A few sub-changes:

   1. Remove the `rating-value` both from the isolated scope and the HTML. It is redundant.
   2. `require` the `ngModel` in the directive definition object.

      ```
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',      // ONE CHANGE IS HERE
            template: '<ul class="rating">' + ...,
            ...
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) { // ANOTHER HERE
                ...
            }
        };
      ```
   3. Use the `ngModel.$modelValue` instead of the `scope.ratingValue`:

      ```
      var updateStars = function() {
          scope.stars = [];
          for (var  i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
              scope.stars.push({filled: i < ngModel.$modelValue}); // CHANGE HERE
          }
      };
      ```
2. Now implement the `ngModel` "interface" for the custom control (the `$render` function), and call `$setViewValue()` to update the model:

   ```
   ngModel.$render = function() {
       updateStars();  // AS SIMPLE AS THAT!
   };

   scope.toggle = function(index) {
       ...
       ngModel.$setViewValue(index + 1);
       ...
   };
   ```
3. For the "required" validation, you can play along with Angular's `ng-required` now. Just "override" `ngModel.$isEmpty()` where you consider zero to be empty, in addition to what Angular thinks that means empty (e.g. `null`):

   ```
   var originalIsEmpty = ngModel.$isEmpty; // KEEP ORIGINAL TO FALL BACK
   ngModel.$isEmpty = function(value) {
       return value === 0 || originalIsEmpty.call(ngModel,value);
   };
   ```
4. And of course add the `ng-disabled` condition to the submission button:

   ```
   <button type="submit" class="..."
       ng-disabled="questionForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
   ```

By the way, there is a mistake in your readonly specification. The scope property is `readonly` but there is a dash in the HTML attribute: `read-only`. Anyway, you do not need this anymore, you have `ng-required`.

Comment: originalIsEmpty.call(ngModel,value) in this what is call function

Comment: Standard JS call ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call))