# inherit angularjs functions in all child elemts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive that show a calender like this :

```
app.directive('noeDatepicker', ['$parse', 'datetimeService', function ($parse, datetimeService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/app/directives/templates/datepicker.html',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            withisrequired: '@'
        },
        require: '^form',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.buttonId = 'date_icon_' + attrs.id;
            scope.inputId = 'date_input_' + attrs.id;
            scope.cancelId = 'date_cancel_' + attrs.id;

            setTimeout(function () {
                Calendar.setup({...});

        }
    };
}
```

});

and my template is this :

```
<div ng-model="model" class="form-inline">
    <input id="{{inputId}}" class="form-control" type="text" isrequired="{{withisrequired}}" ng-model="model" placeholder="1111/01/01" />
    <img id="{{cancelId}}" src="/Content/noe/assets/image/icon/Cancle.svg" width="22" height="22" />
    <img id="{{buttonId}}" src="/Scripts/jalalijscalendar/cal.png" />
</div>
```

but my problem is that when I wanna add for example ng-readonly to this directive, it just add readonly property to div element and input element is not readonly and it accept input from user (see code bellow) :

```
<noe:datepicker model="viewModel.date" id="date1"  name="date1" ng-readonly="true" />
```

I want this ng-readonly function also make all child element in div tag readonly and not just add readonly proptety to div element!

How can i Do that ?

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258651/validate-the-rating-directive-in-angularjs/25259439#25259439) for a solution on validating custom controls.

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update noeDatepicker with

scope:{
      readonly:'=ngReadonly',
      ...
    },
    template: `<div> <input ng-readonly="readonly"/> </div> ...`

basically, you need to add ng-readonly for children elements you want to set.